# Return string-pointer from member-function

Tags: c++, pointers, accessor

I dont understand why I get an error message when I return a char array from an accessor.

in the classdefinition

```
public:
   const char *getString() {
     return _strPtr;
   }
private:
   char* _strPtr;
   int _strLen;
```

then I am trying to access the pointer in the class

```
_strLen = strlen(String.getString());
```

But I get the error message: candidates are const char* getString();

I cannot see what I am doin wrong right now

Thanks in advance!!!

```
String String::operator=(const String& string) {

    // code ..... 

   _strLen = strlen(string.getString());

   //code ...
}
```

Comment: you chave an char* and wants to return an const char*?

Comment: @demonofnight That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to the operator is `const` reference, so the invoked method needs to be `const`:

```
const char* getString() const { .... }
                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: but in the class-definition its declared constant

Comment: @user2991252 No, it is not.